# Google Places Nearby Search

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to fetch a local BMW repair facility for Dortmund, Germany. According to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/BMW+Niederlassung+Dortmund/@51.48488,7.4687013,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47b9178321fec123:0x94dafdcef6e8e1e), there is a BMW dealer nearby to location 51.48488,7.4687013.

The following request matches the above mentioned dealer:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.4842556,7.474081&radius=20000&language=en&name=BMW&key=API_KEY

```
{
    "name": "BMW Niederlassung Dortmund",
    ...,
    "types": [
        "car_repair",
        "car_dealer",
        "store",
        "point_of_interest",
        "establishment"
    ],
    ...,
    "vicinity": "Nortkirchenstraße 111, Dortmund"
}
```

However, if I be more specific on the type (type=car_repair) the above mentioned dealer isn't matched:
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.4842556,7.474081&radius=20000&language=en&name=BMW&type=car_repair&key=API_KEY

I'm pretty sure the second request matched the mentioned dealer in the past...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 12 days, this problem seems to be fixed.